# How can I set 'product_cat' terms from wp_postmeta values?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking to have our woocommerce site display some data that I would like my clients to be able to set through their POS and inventory management software for ease of access.

This data will be stored in the wp_postmeta table.

I'm trying to write a function that will append the value from get_the_meta($id, *custom-meta*, true) to the 'product_cat' taxonomy.

I've played with a few iterations and have not been able to figure things out.

Here is the most recent function that is not working for me, but also not breaking things.

```
function lf_use_meta_as_product_cat() {
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $strain_controller = get_post_meta( $id, 'show strain', true );
    if ( strpos( $strain_controller, 'true') !== false ) {
        $strain = get_post_meta( $id, 'strain', true );
        if ( ! has_term( $strain, 'product_cat', $id ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $id, $strain, 'product_cat', true );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'lf_use_meta_as_product_cat', 10 );
```

The variable I've grabbed with $strain_controller will either be "true" or "false".

I do have a product in the database that has the required post meta, and I know that I can pull and display the meta like such as I have working functions that do so, but I'm not winning.

Comment: `wp_loaded` seems like a weird hook to bind this to - do you really want to do this on _every_ page load? And what have your debugging attempts turned up so far?

Comment: I totally agree with the hook thing, switched it up to use `woocommerce_new_product` and `woocommerce_update_product` - as for debugging it is not throwing any errors anywhere that I can find in debug.log or error_log.

Also switched up to use the product_tag taxonomy, as well as changing my set_object_terms call to `wp_set_object_terms( $id, array($strain), 'product_tag', true)`

No errors in either log pertaining to my function.

Comment: Add a bit of code that writes some debug info into a logfile then. Check if you are really getting the ID as expected there, and what those meta data functions actually return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe for making excellent suggestions, prompting me to figure this out myself.

Here is the code ->

```
function lf_use_meta_as_product_tag() {
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $strain_controller = get_post_meta( $id, 'show strain', true );
    if ( strpos( $strain_controller, 'true') !== false ) {
        
        $strain = get_post_meta( $id, 'strain', true );
        
        if ( ! has_term( $strain, 'product_tag', $id ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $id, $strain, 'product_tag', true );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_product', 'lf_use_meta_as_product_tag', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'lf_use_meta_as_product_tag', 10);
```